# Crossfade background images in a body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the next problem: I want to crossfade different background images of a `<body>` tag, with a timer. You can see [here](https://www.hydearchitects.com/) an example of what I want to achieve.
The problem is that I'm new to these stuff and can't figure out how to do it...I've seen many post, but they only made me get more confused!

my HTML code:

```
<body id="one" onload="startTimer()">
<!-- Some other tags -->
</body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function displayNextImage() {
        x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
        var url = "url(" + images[x] + ")";
        $("#one").css('background-image', url);
    }

    function startTimer() {
      setInterval(displayNextImage, 6000);
    }

    var images = [], x = -1;
    images[0] = "someimage1.jpg";
    images[1] = "someimage2.jpg";
    images[2] = "someimage3.jpg";
</script>
```

and my CSS code:

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/forest1.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I'm open to suggestions, I mean, if there's a better way to do these, great! I just want to get the same point as the web shown above!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any JavaScript, you can achieve it with CSS animations:

```css
body {
    background-size: cover;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeBckg {
  0% {  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000?image=1080"); }
  25% {  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000?image=1081"); }
  50% { background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000?image=1064"); }
  75% {background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000?image=1078"); }
  100% {background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000?image=1080"); }
}

@keyframes changeBckg {
  0% {  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000?image=1080"); }
  25% {  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000?image=1081"); }
  50% { background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000?image=1064"); }
  75% {background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000?image=1078"); }
  100% {background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000?image=1080"); }
}

.letterAnimation {
  -webkit-animation: changeBckg 16s ease infinite;
  animation: changeBckg 16s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<body class="letterAnimation">
  
</body>
```

Comment: Good! if he does not need the arrow keys like in the example provided, otherwise JS is needed,

Comment: your solution is pretty good, I can achieve what I wanted! There's only a problem though, it does not work depending on which browser version you have, would be nice if it could be independently from that @Tedds

Comment: Sure @wj127, the animation property needs browser prefixes, but that's no big deal. I'm editing the snippet in a minute with the prefixes included, sorry I did not warn you.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't know that!! Now yeah, it works perfectly fine! :):) Thanks a lot @Tedds

Comment: Great succinct answer! Very adaptable even if you want to add actual content in the container. One thing I'd like to note though is that SO's preview seems to add this smooth crossfade transition that I just can't replicate when I run the code out of SO. To get it smooth, I had to add my own keyframes that manually handle opacity.

Answer (score 1):

A simple CSS only solution, it works using CSS animations `@keyframes`; You can apply the same code to the body of your html page.

```css
@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#cf4a img:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

#cf4a img:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

#cf4a img:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

#cf4a img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

#cf4a img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: cf4FadeInOut 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf4a" class="shadow cf4FadeInOut">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/01">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/02">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/03">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/04">
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution except that it does not address the `background-image` case.